# Mesa OpenGL Drivers configuration for OpenGL on RHEL7

Tags: rhel, opengl, mesa

Our application needs Opengl 3.1 support or higher.  The RHEL7.9 VM (thru VMware, with the VMware SVGA II adapter) we use, provides the following for glxinfo | grep version:

```
- server glx version string: 1.4
- client glx version string: 1.4
- GLX version: 1.4
-    Max core profile version: 0.0
-    Max compat profile version: 2.1
-    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
-    Max GLES[23] profile version: 2.0
- OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 18.3.4
- OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
- OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 18.3.5
- OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
```

The Wiki for Mesa (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesa_(computer_graphics)) shows 18.x supports OpenGL 4.6 / OpenGL ES 3.2, I am trying to figure out how to configure the default driver in RHEL7 to support that instead of the 2.1/2.0 it shows in glxinfo. (Why would Red Hat set it up by default for OpenGL 2.1 / OpenGL ES 2.0?)

Update:
The underlying hardware is one of a bunch of Dell PowerEdge R730/R740/R830/R840 all of 2015-2017 vintage.  The CPUs on them are Xeon Platinum 8620, a few Xeon Gold something-something, and a few other flavors of Xeon Platinum.  (Some of them we have Nvidia Tesla M10/M60/P40 graphics accelerators, we are trying to do away with)  I asked the Lab Ops manager a couple hours ago what the iGPU capability on those are, and his response "that is a good question".  The CPUs on them are Xeon Platinum 8620, a few Xeon Gold something-something, and a few other flavors of Xeon Platinum.

The interesting thing is that my RHEL8 VM gave me satisfactory glxinfo data, ie. OpenGL 4.6 and OpenGL ES 3.2.  I may have to get the VMs on the same cluster with the same underlying servers to truly be able to tell if the actual physical hw can really do those versions.

Update2:
Both RHEL7 and RHEL8 VM are running on the same cluster of three PowerEdge R730's with Xeon ES-2690 v4 cpus (and identical config across the three servers).
Here is the `glxinfo | grep version` for the RHEL8 VM:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profie version: 4.5
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.1.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.1.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
    GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix,
```

So the RHEL8 driver on the same hardware can support 4.5/ES 3.2, but the RHEL7 drops back to 2.1.

Comment: OpenGL support is an hardware feature mediated by a driver but ultimately limited by the hardware itself. In this case what you see is what you get with the virtualized graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mesa 18 supports *up to* OpenGL 4.6 (4.5 initially), but specific support depends on the driver. The VMware SVGA3D driver in Mesa 18 supports at least OpenGL 3.3 but only if the following are true:

- the VM is configured for virtual hardware version 12 or later (and the host supports that)
- the host system, GPU and graphics driver support OpenGL 4.0 or DirectX 11
- the guest `vmwgfx` kernel driver is version 2.9.0 or later

Failing that, it will fall back to OpenGL 2.1.

Comment: That is great a great answer thank you.   I got some more info to add to the post, it won't fit in this comment.  Note the part I added where the same virtualized server system, with an RHEL8 VM (which has Mesa 21.x drivers by default) gave me OpenGL 4.6 and OpenGL ES 3.2 strings.  (Which meets our needs, except our customer is not ready to move past rhel7--we just got rhel8 VMs set up a week ago)

Comment: How are you connecting to your VMs? If you’re using remote X the VMware support might not matter at all. Regarding your question to your lab ops manager, your Xeons don’t have iGPUs.

Comment: VMware Horizon Client